# Concatenate individual genomic intervals into populational regions

Tags: r, overlap, overlapping, bioconductor

I would like to concatenate individual genomic intervals into common regions.

My input:

```
dfin <- "chr start end sample type
        1   10    20   NE1    loss
        1   5     15   NE2    gain
        1   25    30   NE1    gain
        2   40    50   NE1    loss
        2   40    60   NE2    loss
        3   20    30   NE1    gain"
dfin <- read.table(text=dfin, header=T)
```

My expected output:

```
dfout <- "chr start end samples type
        1   5     20   NE1-NE2  both
        1   25    30   NE1      gain
        2   40    60   NE1-NE2  loss
        3   20    30   NE1      gain"
dfout <- read.table(text=dfout, header=T)
```

The intervals in `dfin` will never overlap in the same animal, just between animals (columns `sample` and `samples`, respectively). The column `type` have two factors (`loss`and `gain`) in `dfin` and is expected to have three factors in `dfout` (`loss`, `gain` and `both`, which occur when the concatenated region in `dfout` was based on both `loss` and `gain`).

Any idea to deal with that?

*Updated for @David Arenburg

Comment: I don't think there's a simple fix for this that will create everything in one go.  I would start by sorting by `chr` and `start` then creating the merged intervals.  After that check to see if the each in `dfin` is contained in each `dfout` interval and updating `samples` and `type` accordingly.  This should involve a little bit of logic and programming, but I don't think there's a quick fix.

Comment: You could find helpful the "IRanges" package; `reduce(RangedData(space = dfin$chr, IRanges(dfin$start, dfin$end)))`

Comment: @alexis_laz, your code worked pretty well for my real data set. Please write a formal answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(expanding on the comment) You could use the "IRanges" package:

```
library(IRanges)

#build an appropriate object
dat = RangedData(space = dfin$chr, 
                 IRanges(dfin$start, dfin$end), 
                 sample = dfin$sample, 
                 type = dfin$type)
dat
#concatenate overlaps with an extra step of saving the concatenation mappings
ans = RangedData(reduce(ranges(dat), with.revmap = TRUE))
ans
```

Could not figure out how to avoid `reduce` losing columns of "RangedData" object, but having the mappings saved we could do something like (there might be a more appropriate -according to "IRanges"- way to extract mappings, but I was not able to find it):

```
tmp = elementMetadata(ranges(ans)@unlistData)$revmap@partitioning
maps = rep(seq_along(start(tmp)), width(tmp))
maps
#[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
```

Having the mappings of interval concatenation, we could aggregate "sample" and "type" to get the final form. E.g.:

```
tapply(dfin$sample, maps, function(X) paste(unique(X), collapse = "-"))
#        1         2         3         4 
#"NE1-NE2"     "NE1" "NE1-NE2"     "NE1"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an attempt to group the intervals using `data.table::foverlaps` and then calculate all the rest

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(dfin), chr, start, end)
res <- foverlaps(dfin, dfin, which = TRUE)[, toString(xid), by = yid
                                           ][, indx := .GRP, by = V1]$indx
dfin[, .(
          chr = chr[1L],
          start = min(start), 
          end = max(end), 
          samples = paste(unique(sample), collapse = "-"),
          type = if(uniqueN(type) > 1L) "both" else as.character(type[1L])
         ),
       by = res]

#    res chr start end samples type
# 1:   1   1     5  20 NE2-NE1 both
# 2:   2   1    25  30     NE1 gain
# 3:   3   2    40  60 NE1-NE2 loss
# 4:   4   3    20  30     NE1 gain
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect for my example, but it was too simplistic. I have several intervals in the same `chr`. Thus, they need to be turned into a common region just if they have overlap. Please check my new example!